# Why my web page is not running with proper alignment only with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have created one web page using twitter bootstrap and that works fine with all browsers except Internet explorer 9. For this problem I've googled and I got one clue to use developer tool of IE by pressing F12. While using that developer tool I changed document mode from quirks to IE standard 9 and 8 which given me output in very same format that I was requiring or we can say which given me output as same like other browsers given me..

So my question: is that what changed I need to do in my phtml page?

I have already tried for Doctype changes but it doesn't worked for me

Comment: Try puting this above the <html> tag: 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I have played with Doctype but doesnt get any effect

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your page header

```
<!-- this meta tag is used to force IE9 to work with HTML5 and CSS3 -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Of course, `<!DOCTYPE html>`